# How to select module name in urlfor function inside template

Tags: go, beego

Im working in a beego application with 2 modules, and has a controller with the same name in both modules.
When I use `{{urlfor}}` in template the generated url is linking with the other module.

Anybody know if its posible select module name in `urlfor` function? I search in the docs and cant see any reference about. Im currently use beego 1.4.3

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody with the same issue:

The problem is how I implemented the application folder structure for modules. It seems not be compatible with `{{urlfor}}`.

The correct answer come from github: https://github.com/astaxie/beego/issues/1100

In the link you can found the correct directory tree